rb-readline still needed in Ruby 2.7?
I am updating an ancient Ruby on Rails project. One of the Gems I have found is rb-readline, which seems to be dead. The Readme of the Gem says that it is a pure-Ruby implementation of readline basically because getting readline on Windows is a problem (the Readme file dates from 2016). Now I am on a Mac and anyway, this is all such a long time ago. Am I right in supposing I can delete the Gem?

Yes, you're right. Nowadays its trivial to run linux on WSL on windows and installing readline is not an issue unless you're silly enough to not use WSL.

As @max has stated in his comment, the Gem can be safely deleted.
